# a better way to write inline css in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive in AngularJS for tags like `<mytextarea class="custom_mta default_mtastyle" width="30" height="40" x="150" y="50">text here</mytextarea>`

normally I'll have the attributes of the example but it is not a comprehensive list and I might not have some of them. I have to transform them to CSS.
the code below doesn't work perfectly. for example if width is not defined, it should be 'auto', not zero, or just not included in the css part.

```js
.directive('mytextarea', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true, 
  transclude: true,
  template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    /* add unique properties for this directive */
    var newcss = 'width:' + (attrs.width | 0) + 'px; height:' + attrs.height + 'px;';
    attrs.$set('style', 'color:red;' + newcss);

    /* remove attributes that are no longer needed */
    element
        .removeAttr('width')
        .removeAttr('height');

    /* and set a default class */
    attrs.$set('class', 'default_subscreen ' + attrs.class );
  }
}
```

is there a better way to write this? I experimented with JSON syntax:

```
var mystyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: attrs.x,
    width: attrs.width
}

attrs.$set('style', mystyle); // but mystyle is an object! should I use a filter?
```

Maybe I can run functions on the values? like `(attrs.width)?attrs.width:0;`
I also remember taht some things in JS  can be written like `var s = "my string" + (attrs.width | 0)`. Where can I get an extended explanation about it?
I have a few more components that need similar logic in their directives and I'm looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: Write a function which converts that `mystyle` object to a style string so you can do `attrs.$set('style', createStyle(mystyle));`

Comment: where shall I declare it? I have to use it in more than one module

Comment: I guess you could make a service for it, been a long while since I touched angular so I'm not 100% on that

Comment: I finally augmented $scope: I store all properties in scope.properties because I mutate (and inherit) all those styles. I got a service that creates the inline css from that object. for example, if I have properties x and y (coordinates in the legacy XML that I'm feeding AngularJS), my css should be "position:absolute;top...". that service creates the correct string.